# Programmatically setting wallpaper on lock screen for Samsung TouchWiz devices?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-wallpaper, samsung-touchwiz

I have built an app that changes users wallpaper on a timer. I use the standard WallpaperManager.setWallpaper function, and things work great on AOSP-based devices.

However, on some OEM platforms like TouchWiz, it doesn't work for the lock screen (it only sets the launcher wallpaper). Is it possible to fix this? I'm willing to use reflection to access OEM APIs if there is a place to start.

Thanks!